# (Tiny, very few, raindrops of) Water got into computer

Tags: cpu, motherboard

my CPU was placed next to a window and due to rain a tiny amount of raindrops entered into it. This happened around 3 hours back.

Water on the top of the case was a tiny bit and inside I could only see a single drop on the wire bundle. I wiped the top clean. About an hour after cursing myself, I opened the case but couldn't find any drops.

What should I do to ensure my computer would still work?

[image: Area from where water entered]

Comment: Although water causes many problems to electronics, it's not a magical poison that makes the whole thing break instantly if a single drop gets inside. If the water's dried out, then your computer is almost certainly fine. If the water doesn't touch the actual electrical parts inside, then your computer is almost certainly fine (but you should let it dry out, to make sure). A few drops of water on the outside of a cable, not in the connectors - also probably fine. Actually, most cables would still be okay if the middle section was submerged in liquid water. That's what the insulation is for.

Comment: Remove all power sources - mains, battery etc. Let it dry.

Answer (score 4):

In general with an electronic device, if rainwater or other fresh water gets into it, **immediately** remove any external power (turn it off and **unplug** it) and any batteries and allow it to dry thoroughly. The time for that will depend on whether it was warm to begin with and the RH in the vicinity of the device. Removing the CMOS battery in a desktop is a bit inconvenient and may not be necessary if the water didn't make its way to that area of the motherboard.

If it was salt water rather than rainwater, you would have a much more serious problem.

In this case, it sounds like it didn't really get all that wet.

Answer (score 3):

It should be absolutely fine, if there's no water visible and only a few drops went in it's likely already dried out.